# Retrieving data from a MySQL Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following ruby script that I am using to try to retrieve data from my MySQL database. I am using rails 3.2.

```
require 'active_record'  
require 'mysql2'


ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    adapter:  'mysql2',
     host:     'localhost',
     database: 'financials',
     username: 'dbuser',
)
class Financials < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :symbol, :cur_price....
end

fin = Financials.new

puts fin.find_by symbol: 'arrs'
```

The database itself contains the following record:

```
symbol      cur_price   52low   52high   avg_vol
arrs        16.50       11.70   17.98    1062020
```

When I run my script I get the following error:

```
method_missing': undefined method `find_by' for #<Financials:0x007fc54b8ddbd8> (NoMethodError)
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rails it should be

```
Financials.find_by_symbol('arrs')
```

and it you are using Rails 3.x

```
Financials.where(symbol: 'arrs').first
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am using rails 3.x and the where clause worked, but it returned #<Financials:0x007f898b404f68>, how do I get the actual content?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by content - it returned one Financials object, you can call `fin = Financials.where(symbol: 'arrs').first; fin.cur_price` or any other column name to get column content

Comment: FYI: when you call `puts fin` you are actually calling `to_s` method of fin and that for active record models produces output like in your comment `<Financials:0x007f898b404f68>`

Comment: got it, so then would I have to do something like puts fin.to_f  ?

Comment: Thanks got it now. I appreciate the time!

Comment: @rahrahruby can I acess the databse without the model pattern